# Create table at runtime in predefined database

Tags: android, android-sqlite

In my app I have prepopulated database with some tables. It is located in assets. I can access data in that database with no problems.

However, in one of my activities I am trying to create another table at runtime in that database. The creation method does not produce any errors, however when I try to query that new table I get `no such table exception`.

Any ideas why it's not working?

EDIT 1: Code to create a new table

```
    myDb = openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    String create = "create table if not exists' " + TABLE_FAVORITES
            + "'('_id' integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + "'proverb' text not null);";      
    myDb.execSQL(create);
```

Code to check if `String proverb` is already in db:

```
Cursor cur = myDb.query(false, TABLE_FAVORITES,
                new String[] { "proverb" }, "proverb=?",
                new String[] { proverb }, null, null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: Add code to create and query...........

Comment: Can you post the code using which you are creating a table in assets? May be we can help you then!!

Comment: After create the table in database , just have alook on the your db file there is any table created or not ?

Comment: Yes, I imported database file and opened it in Firefox's sqlite manager. The table is there.

Comment: I am sure that your table is not creating if you added the correct code. `"create table if not exists' " +` should be as `"create table if not exists '" +`. Observe an space after `exists`.  To make sure just clear data and then try.

Comment: @PankajKumar this is strange it worked after I tried your suggestion. however, these statements look the same for me as there is a space between ' and "